# add multiple data using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to add multiple data in jquery ajax.
i try like this but not working,

i take a data from this `span`.

`<span id="<?php echo $tutorial_id; ?>" modes="<?php echo $modesearch ?>" searchs="<?php echo $searchstring ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Show more</span>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        var MODESEARCH = $(this).attr('modes');
        var SEARCHSTRING = $(this).attr('searchs');
        $('.show_more').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'getDataS.php',
            data:'idpost='+ID,
            data:'modesearch='+MODESEARCH,
            data:'searchstring='+SEARCHSTRING,
            success:function(html){
                $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
                $('.tutorial_list').append(html);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
```

when i try to run it, result always showing the latest `data`.

in this case just showing data from `searchstring`.

Comment: You can't duplicate property names in an object such as using 2 `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this would be to combine your query strings with an ampersand:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'getDataS.php',
    data: 'idpost=' + ID + '&modesearch=' + MODESEARCH + '&searchstring=' + SEARCHSTRING,
    success: function(html) {
        $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
        $('.tutorial_list').append(html);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can simply pass JSON data, remembering to wrap your keys in quotation marks:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'getDataS.php',
    data: {'idpost': ID, 'modesearch': MODESEARCH, 'searchstring': SEARCHSTRING},
    success: function(html) {
        $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
        $('.tutorial_list').append(html);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: *"pass JSON data"* ... not really what that is

Answer (score 2):

You can send the data as a json object like `{ idpost : ID, modesearch : MODESEARCH, searchstring : SEARCHSTRING }`

```
$.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'getDataS.php',
      data:{ idpost : ID, modesearch : MODESEARCH, searchstring : SEARCHSTRING },
       success:function(html){
            $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
            $('.tutorial_list').append(html);
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
You can also try
   
   var formData = 
        {
            'idpost'              : ID,
            'modesearch'          : MODESEARCH,
            'searchstring'        : searchstring
        };
         $.ajax({
            type        : 'GET', 
            url         : 'data.php',
            data        : formData, 
            success : function(html)
            {
            $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
            $('.tutorial_list').append(html);
              
          
             }
        });
```